# Python check if a string has characters

Tags: python

I am processing 500GB of data to find only the lines which has Characters.
Can you suggest me a efficent/Faster way.

```
Data is like:
%^^%^^%^^%
This is a valid 
*%^%^ Valid
This is not a valid one
```

output should be:

```
Data is like:
This is a valid 
*%^%^ Valid
This is not a valid one
```

I am trying this:
isalpha()
issue is it will remoce the line
    *%^%^ Valid

Actuall some how this code is also not working

```
if line.isalpha()=='True':
  print(line)
```

This is not working...

can I use regular expressions but read some where it will slow it is that true?

Comment: `'True'` is a `str`.  `True` is a `bool`.

Comment: `.isalpha()` returns a boolean value: either `True` or `False`.  Neither of those values is equal to the string `'True'`.

Comment: Firstly, `True != "True"`. Secondly, you didn't explain anything how the string is valid or not?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the fastest way would be to check the first character of each line, and if it is alpha, keep it, otherwise check the next character, etc. Are there more assumptions we can make to speed it up?

Comment: ooh thank you I corrected the True . sorry missed that..ut still it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using [isalpha](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) correctly, it returns `True` when all characters in the string are alphabetic.

You could try using `any` and `map` to make sure at least one character is alphabet in the line.

```
txt = """
Data is like:
%^^%^^%^^%
This is a valid 
*%^%^ Valid
This is not a valid one
"""

for line in txt.split("\n"):
    if any(map(str.isalpha, line)):
        print(line)
```

prints:

```
Data is like:
This is a valid 
*%^%^ Valid
This is not a valid one
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex, like:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\A[%|\^]*$')
>>>
>>> pattern.match('%^ Text')  # no match
>>> pattern.match('%^^%^')  # match
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='%^^%^'>
```